# Assignment by product (multiplication assignment) with increment or decrement in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, variable-assignment, increment, multiplication

Why do we get different results for the two follow statements:

```
int x = 5;
x = x * x++;
```

the output is 26; whereas the next example returns 30, though they are same?!

```
int x = 5;
x *= x++;
```

Thank you

Comment: Isn't that undefined? (both of them)

Comment: Both are undefined behavior. The stored value of a variable shall not be modified more than once between sequence points.

Comment: Do you mean that the behaviour is unexpected?!

Comment: The behaviour is implementation-dependent. You can get different results depending on the compiler used.

Comment: *Undefined behaviour* means, you are wrong no matter what you expect. *Undefined behaviour* means, you do not have any justified reason to expect any particular result.

Comment: @kuroi No, the behavior is genuinely undefined. *Implementation-defined* is another class, for example, how the `NULL` macro is defined is implementation-defined.

Comment: @llnspectable : you're right. I was too quick to answer this one. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

These both exhibit undefined behaviour in both C++03 and C++11. In C++11 terminology, you can't have two unsequenced modifications of the same scalar or a modification and a value computation using the same scalar, otherwise you have undefined behaviour.

```
x = x * x++;
```

In this case, incrementing `x` (a modification) is unsequenced with the other two value computation of `x`.

```
x *= x++;
```

In this case, incrementing `x` is unsequenced with the value computation of `x` on the left.

For the meaning of undefined behaviour, see C++11 §1.3.24:

> **undefined behavior**
>   behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

Comment: *"incrementing `x` is unsequenced"* that is, the modification of `x` is unsequenced to the other two value computations. (It is sequenced after the value computation of the `x++`.)

Comment: I'm just wondering, what's the reasoning for undefined and not just unspecified evaluation order?

Comment: @user2345215 I'm fairly sure it's to allow the compilers to perform optimizations under the assumption that the programmer doesn't do this. Somebody else might have a better answer though.

Comment: The compiler is supposed to let some operations run simultaneously (on different CPU cores). Hardware might do bizarre things (e.g. generate junk or throw an exception) when 2 cores read and write the same variable simultaneously. Since UB allows doing these things, compiler has much less to worry about when deciding how to do parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a ++'d value to the original value is undefined behavior. So it makes sense that assigning a ++'d then multiplied value is also undefined.